# Exception Inheritance in ExamLab

Tags: java

This code is from Exam lab

```
  abstract class AbsA{
      public void play()throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.print("Playing AbsA");
      }
    }

abstract class AbsB extends AbsA{
  public abstract void play();  //Line 2
}

class NonC extends AbsB{
  public void play(){
    System.out.print("Playing NonC");
  }
}

class NonD extends NonC{
  public void play(){
    System.out.print("Playing NonD");
  }
}

public class MC{
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    AbsA d=new NonC();
    d.play();
  }
}
```

I have few doubts
1) i learned that your parent class must throw broader exception then your child class
   As in case of class **AbsA** play() method is throwing checked exception and when this method is inherited to **AbsB** class is implicitly throwing the RuntimeException.
How it is possible?

2) Moreover at line 2 , the inherited method is with abstract keyword. Is it possible?

Comment: Just making sure: This isn't a _current_ exam, is it?

Comment: yes it is from current exam

Answer (score 0):

A method has to declare in the `throws` clause any *checked* exceptions that it wants to throw. However, it is free to not throw them. For example, AbsA's play method does not actually throw anything. So, it is also fine for AbsB to extend play() and have no `throws` clause at all. So, this is okay:

```
abstract class AbsB extends AbsA {
    public abstract void play();
}
```

This is also okay...

```
abstract class AbsB extends AbsA {
    public abstract void play() throws InterruptedException;
}
```

...because AbsB's play method is declaring as thrown the same exceptions as in the superclass.

This is okay too...

```
abstract class AbsB extends AbsA {
    public abstract void play() throws NullPointerException;
}
```

...because NullPointerException is an *unchecked* exception (it is a subclass of RuntimeException). You can *always* throw unchecked exceptions, whether they are declared as thrown or not. The `throws` clause in this case doesn't do anything, because the method could throw a NullPointerException anyway, but it may help to document the intended behavior of the method:

This will not compile:

```
abstract class AbsB extends AbsA {
    public abstract void play() throws IOException;
}
```

IOException is a checked exception. AbsB cannot override AbsA's play method to throw new types of checked exceptions, because if it did, an instance of AbsB would not be a valid instance of AbsA.

> The inherited method is with abstract keyword. Is it possible?

Yes. It's really uncommon to override a non-abstract method and make it abstract, but it is legal and sometimes useful. AbsA's play method says "Playing AbsA". AbsB is abstract, so there will never be need for a message "Playing AbsB". However, AbsB makes the method abstract so that non-abstract children like NonC are forced to reimplement the method and cannot inherit it from AbsA.